# Apollo Client sending requests to wrong uri

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo Client to send requests to a graphql server. I created a link with apollo-upload-client since I need it for what I'm doing. The client is defined as follows:

```
const link = createUploadLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
});

const client = new ApolloClient({link});
```

However, when I try to make a mutation, it sends the request to http://localhost:3000/graphql instead. This results in a failed request, as that is not where the server is. Strangely, requests work fine if I specify the uri directly in the client like this:

```
client = new ApolloClient({uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql});
```

At first I thought it might be a problem with createUploadLink, but even using HttpLink causes this problem.
Why does the client request the wrong address when using links?

Comment: What is `createUploadLink`? But I bet the URI specified there is for the upload endpoint, not for the graphql endpoint.

Comment: It's from apollo-upload-client. I ran into the same problem when I was using an HttpLink combined with a custom ApolloLink, so I don't know if it's specific to that library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was where I was importing ApolloClient from. I was originally importing it from apollo-boost. It worked when I imported it from @apoloo/client.